# Zkteco iface 950 Time and attendance record

Tags: zkteco

I hope this message finds you well. I have a question regarding the ZKTeco iFace 950 devices. I have two devices, and I've noticed a discrepancy in their behavior.

When I change the time on one of the devices to a week or two weeks ago and attempt to register attendance, it successfully records the entry. However, the second device does not seem to acknowledge this change, and instead, it marks the entry as a repetition without recording the attendance.

I'm wondering if there are specific settings or configurations that need to be adjusted to ensure both devices respond consistently to changes in time. If anyone has experience with this issue or can provide guidance on the settings needed to address this discrepancy, I would greatly appreciate your input.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Best regards,

Comment: You are using a ZKBiosecurity or ZK CVSecurity server, right?

Comment: No I'm not using that program..